# Filling in holes in heightmap with lower resolution heightmaps?

Tags: qgis, elevation

I have this elevation map of the Verdal area in Norway, from the Norwegian mapping authority. The first one has a 1m resolution, but has some holes in the data. I'd like to fill in those holes with the corresponding area of the second height map, which has a 10m resolution, and merge them into one layer.

Data is from https://hoydedata.no/LaserInnsyn/ (Center coordinates ca 63.79142°N 11.43853°E, Nasjonal Høydemodell/National Elevation Model)

[image]

[image]

Does anyone know how to do this?

I am new to GIS software.

Comment: That's very interesting that their DEM would have holes in it. It's not simply an artifact of how the layer is being symbolized? Could you edit your question to provide links to the source data, if possible?

Comment: I have added a link to the page I downloaded the data from!